# SQL Create Table and Data

Tags: sql, sql-insert, create-table, insert-into

I am learning SQL and wanted to create a simple table:

```
Create table kante (v int, n int);
INSERT INTO kante VALUES (1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (2,3), (4,5);
SELECT * from kante;
```

However, when using these online editors I always get error messages.

- https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in
- http://sqlfiddle.com/

Could you help me where my mistake is?
Thank you

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your code uses non-standard syntax). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using postgresql, oracle, sql-server, db2, ...

Comment: w3fools is a bad place to start to begin with. That site is fool of errors

Comment: Your code works for me: http://rextester.com/PZDG79299

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's a bad idea to insert it at the same time,
try this:

```
INSERT INTO kante(v,n) VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO kante(v,n) VALUES (2,3);....
```

Answer (score 0):

First, whenever using `insert`, learn to list the columns being inserted.  So the `insert` should look like:

```
INSERT INTO kante(v, n)
    VALUES (1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (2,3), (4,5);
```

That won't affect whether your code works; it is just a good idea.

Two things come to mind.  If you are calling this from code, then you might be including multiple statements in a call that expects only one.  However, you don't mention any such language.

Second, not all databases support multiple row inserts with `VALUES`.  For instance, your code definitely works in MySQL (see SQL Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/144162/1)).  However, it would not work in Oracle.

So, you can probably fix your problem by using multiple `INSERT` statements:

```
INSERT INTO kante(v, n) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO kante(v, n) VALUES (2, 3);
INSERT INTO kante(v, n) VALUES (3, 4);
INSERT INTO kante(v, n) VALUES (2, 3);
INSERT INTO kante(v, n) VALUES (4, 5);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now. Could you help me why SQL Fiddle might fail when I execute this afterwards?

WITH pfad (v,n) as (SELECT v,n from kante) 
UNION ALL
(Select k.V, p.N FROM Kante k, pfad p)
WHERE k.N=p.V
SELECT * FROM pfad;

Answer (score 0):

Try one at a time

```
Create table kante (v int, n int);
INSERT INTO kante (n,v) VALUES (1,2);
INSERT INTO kante (n,v) VALUES (2,6);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you try to run the 3 statements together. Try to run each statement separately. ie, to be clear first run the `CREATE` statement, then the `INSERT` statement and finally the `SELECT` query.